# scanning an array and assign it into other place in C

Tags: c

help me. I've been assign to make an application for some test result. but why can't I print out what user have inputted at case 2. I've tried other approach but it's not working. this is the closest I could get there. Any help would be appreciated. super thanks +_+

this is my code :

```
int main(){
    int option;
    char namamurid[30][15];
    int i=0,j=0;
    int listening[15];
    int reading[15];
    int essay[15];
    int score[15];

    do{ printf("\"Smart English\" Course Center\n********************************\n");
        printf("1.Add new data\n2.View data\n3.View summary\n4.Exit\n\n");
        printf("your option[1..4]: ");
        scanf("%d",&option);
        fflush(stdin);

        switch(option){
            case 1: 
                do{
                    printf("Input student's name[1..25 char]: ");
                    scanf("%[^\n]s",namamurid[i]);
                    fflush(stdin);
                }while(strlen(namamurid[i])<1 || strlen(namamurid[i])>25);

                do{
                    printf("Correct answer for listening section[0..20]: ");
                    scanf("%d",&listening[i]);
                    fflush(stdin);
                }while(listening[i]<0 || listening[i]>20);

                do{
                    printf("Correct answer for reading section[0..30]: ");
                    scanf("%d",&reading[i]);
                    fflush(stdin);

                }while(reading[i]<0 || reading[i]>30);

                do{
                    printf("Correct answer for essay section[0..25]: ");
                    scanf("%d",&essay[i]);
                    fflush(stdin);

                }while(essay[i]<0 || essay[i]>25);
                break;


            case 2:
                printf("Name\t\tListening\tReading\tEssay\tScore\tGrade\n");
                for(j=0;j<i;j++)
                {
                    printf("%-1s\t\t%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\n",namamurid[j],listening[j],reading[j],essay[j],score[j]);
                }

                break;
        }
    } while(option<1 || option>4 || option !=4);

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"%[^\n]s"` --> `"%[^\n]"`: the `s` is not part of the scanset directive. Also note that `fflush(stdin)` causes undefined behavior according to the Standard (though the behavior is defined on some systems) and is at best not portable. There are better ways of dealing with extra characters left in the input stream. You may be able to get away with adding a leading space to the format string to consume previous newline characters: `" %[^\n]"`.

Comment: First of all, it looks like you don't have any i++ in your loop or sth like that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. I've corrected it. appreciate it so much <3

Answer (score 0):

There is no change to value of variable i which is set to 0 during initialization.Hence it will never enter the for loop in case 2.